# Assert response starts with

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to assert the response, to check if the response value starts with a certain text. I tried using the function `startsWith` but it seems like it does not work in SOPAUI script assertion.

This is what I have tried:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent.records
//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
//log.info jsonSlurper

assert jsonSlurper.startsWith("Text")
```

Here is the json response

```
{
  "Name": "Natalie",
  "message": "What are you doing"
}
```

I want to check if the `Name` starts with "Nat"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAPUI Groovy \[assert reponse starts with\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663725/soapui-groovy-assert-reponse-starts-with)

Comment: Don't ask a new question, edit your old one.

Comment: @protea `JsonSlurper().parseText()` return a data structure of `lists` and `maps` so you can not use `startsWith` directly. What are you trying to achieve? You want to check that some key in your json starts with `Text`? Please provide you `json` response, this way maybe the question becomes clear `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation [`JsonSlurper().parseText(String text)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html#parseText(java.lang.String)) returns:

> data structure of `lists` and `maps`

so you can not use `startsWith` directly. To achieve what you want you have to go to the desired object in the path and use `startsWith` there. Something like must works for your case:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper    

def jsonStr = '{ "Name": "Natalie", "message": "What are you doing" }'

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)
assert jsonSlurper.Name.startsWith("Nat")
```